# Textview style after adding dynamically

Tags: android, styles, textview

My question is how to set a textView style after adding it dynamically.

Here is the code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linarLay);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("TEST1");        
layout.addView(textView);
```

I can see the text view that has been added but.. I need to style it now..
So far I tried  this:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.textStyle);
```

I tried this code after layout.addView(textView); and before it is just same doesn't change a thing..

Any idea/solution would be appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style doesn't change because though you use the same `TextView` object to set style after adding it to `Layout`,it is not a part of layout. You have to get the `View` added,from layout using its id and when you change its style,it would directly be affected to your view on `Layout`.

Try this: (I have not tested but *should work)

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linarLay);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("TEST1");
textView.setId(999);      // give some id  
layout.addView(textView);

TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(999);
tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.textStyle);
```

Comment: No change still.. Your solution is quite good but In this part
(TextView)findViewById(999) I think it has to be R.id.999 but when I do this change it can't find the view before compiling.
And after compiling I think it can't find the view by (TextView)findViewById(999).. Any idea ?

Comment: @Ghostology: I have implemented the same code in one of my app and it was running perfectly. It would find TextView by id 999.There won't be any problem. Have you tried implementing it? any error you got?

Comment: try changing text instead of style..just to be sure,it is getting TextView of layout.If text is changed,then there must be problem in your style.

Comment: I've made a sample app and tried the code it works... But I'm afraid it doesn't take the android:background, android:layout_width, android:layout_height,android:layout_margin and android:layout_alignParentLeft..

But really thanks.. appreciating your help.

Comment: But I see with researching I see things like tv.setBackgroundResource and yes your answer is the perfect solution to the issue..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to do the same with a button. You can set every property programmatically.

You can create a class with a set of methods like the one below:

```
private void setButtonStyle(Button b, String text)
{
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

    b.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_button));
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    b.setText(text);
    b.setLayoutParams(param);
    b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    b.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    b.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, R.color.button_shadow_colour);
    b.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.button_text_colour));
}
```

As you can see it is possible to set everything you need. As an example the param variable has 3 arguments in its contructor which are layout_width, layout_height and weight. So you can do the same with TextView.

Comment: The question is I add textView dynamically to linear layout.. so I think your solution is if you select the button or textview findViewById or?

Answer (score 2):

deprecated since API 23:
     <strike>textView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.Headline);</strike>

so choose:

```
 textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.Headline);
```